# Google Foobar Level 4 RunningWithTheBunnies StackOverFlow

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, stack-overflow, graph-theory

I am facing the StackOverFlow Exception for an unknown input. I tried locally many testcases, but couldn't find one. But when submitting my solution, i am encountering it. Can someone point me out the testcase i am missing or suggest a better approach?

**Question and my code are given below**

> You and your rescued bunny prisoners need to get out of this collapsing death trap of a space station - and fast! Unfortunately, some of the bunnies have been weakened by their long imprisonment and can't run very fast. Their friends are trying to help them, but this escape would go a lot faster if you also pitched in. The defensive bulkhead doors have begun to close, and if you don't make it through in time, you'll be trapped! You need to grab as many bunnies as you can and get through the bulkheads before they close.

> The time it takes to move from your starting point to all of the bunnies and to the bulkhead will be given to you in a square matrix of integers. Each row will tell you the time it takes to get to the start, first bunny, second bunny, ..., last bunny, and the bulkhead in that order. The order of the rows follows the same pattern (start, each bunny, bulkhead). The bunnies can jump into your arms, so picking them up is instantaneous, and arriving at the bulkhead at the same time as it seals still allows for a successful, if dramatic, escape. (Don't worry, any bunnies you don't pick up will be able to escape with you since they no longer have to carry the ones you did pick up.) You can revisit different spots if you wish, and moving to the bulkhead doesn't mean you have to immediately leave - you can move to and from the bulkhead to pick up additional bunnies if time permits.

> In addition to spending time traveling between bunnies, some paths interact with the space station's security checkpoints and add time back to the clock. Adding time to the clock will delay the closing of the bulkhead doors, and if the time goes back up to 0 or a positive number after the doors have already closed, it triggers the bulkhead to reopen. Therefore, it might be possible to walk in a circle and keep gaining time: that is, each time a path is traversed, the same amount of time is used or added.

> Write a function of the form answer(times, time_limit) to calculate the most bunnies you can pick up and which bunnies they are, while still escaping through the bulkhead before the doors close for good. If there are multiple sets of bunnies of the same size, return the set of bunnies with the lowest prisoner IDs (as indexes) in sorted order. **The bunnies are represented as a sorted list by prisoner ID, with the first bunny being 0. There are at most 5 bunnies, and time_limit is a non-negative integer that is at most 999.**

```
For instance, in the case of  
[  
    [0, 2, 2, 2, -1],  # 0 = Start  
    [9, 0, 2, 2, -1],  # 1 = Bunny 0  
    [9, 3, 0, 2, -1],  # 2 = Bunny 1  
    [9, 3, 2, 0, -1],  # 3 = Bunny 2  
    [9, 3, 2, 2,  0],  # 4 = Bulkhead  
]
```

and a time limit of 1, the five inner array rows designate the starting point, bunny 0, bunny 1, bunny 2, and the bulkhead door exit respectively. You could take the path:

```
Start End Delta Time Status
    -   0     -    1 Bulkhead initially open
    0   4    -1    2
    4   2     2    0
    2   4    -1    1
    4   3     2   -1 Bulkhead closes
    3   4    -1    0 Bulkhead reopens; you and the bunnies exit
```

With this solution, you would pick up bunnies 1 and 2. This is the best combination for this space station hallway, so the answer is [1, 2].

## Test cases

Inputs:

```
(int) times = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]  
(int) time_limit = 3
```

Output:

```
(int list) [0, 1]
```

Inputs:

```
(int) times = [[0, 2, 2, 2, -1], [9, 0, 2, 2, -1], [9, 3, 0, 2, -1], [9, 3, 2, 0, -1], [9, 3, 2, 2, 0]]  
(int) time_limit = 1
```

Output:

```
(int list) [1, 2]
```

**My Code**
What i basically do is that i first check if there is a **negative cycle or not.** If yes, then all the bunnies can be rescued. and If not, then i basically do a dfs.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class RunningWithTheBunnies
{
    public static int maxCount = 0;
    public static int[] toReturn = null;
    public static int[] arr = new int[5];
    public static int rows = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int rows = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int[][] times = new int[rows][rows];
        String[] arr = null;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
        {
            arr = br.readLine().split(" ");
            for(int j = 0 ; j < rows ; j++)
            {
                times[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(arr[j]);
            }
        }
        int time_limit = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println(answer(times,time_limit));
        for(int i = 0 ; i < toReturn.length ; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(toReturn[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }


    public static int[] answer(int[][] times,int time_limit)
    {
        rows = times.length;
        int containsCycle = containsNegativeCycle(times);
        if(containsCycle == 1){
            System.out.println("has negative cycle");// for degubbing
            toReturn = new int[rows - 2];
            for(int i = 0 ; i < rows - 2 ; i++)
            {
                toReturn[i] = i;
            }
            return toReturn;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("has no negative cycle");// for debugging
            //return new int[2];
            int[] visiting = new int[rows];
            for(int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
            {
                visiting[i] = -2;
            }
            dfs(0,0,time_limit,visiting,times);
            return toReturn;
        }
    }

public static void dfs(int vertex,int count,int timeStatus,int[] visiting,int[][] times)
{
    if(timeStatus < -1)
        return;
    System.out.println("at vertex : " + vertex + ", with status = " + timeStatus);// for debugging purpose.

    visiting[vertex] = timeStatus;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
    {
        if(i != vertex && visiting[i] == -2 && timeStatus - times[vertex][i] > -2)
        {
            //arr[count] = i;
            //dfs(vertex,count + 1,timeStatus - times[vertex][i],visiting,times);
            if(i != 0 && i != rows - 1)
            {
                arr[count] = i - 1;
                dfs(i,count + 1,timeStatus - times[vertex][i],visiting,times);
            }
            else
            {
                dfs(i,count,timeStatus - times[vertex][i],visiting,times);
            }
        }
        // else if(i != vertex && (visiting[i] < timeStatus - times[vertex][i] || i == rows - 1 || i == 0) && timeStatus - times[vertex][i] > -2)
         else if(i != vertex && timeStatus - times[vertex][i] > -2)
        {
            dfs(i,count,timeStatus - times[vertex][i],visiting,times);
        }
    }
     if(vertex == rows - 1 && timeStatus >= 0 && arr.length > maxCount)
    {
        toReturn = new int[arr.length];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
        {
            toReturn[i] = arr[i];
            System.out.println("added " + toReturn[i] + ",at i = " + i );// for debugging
        }
        maxCount = arr.length;
    }

    visiting[vertex] = -2;
}

    public static int containsNegativeCycle(int[][] times)
    {
        int[] dist = new int[rows];
        dist[0] = 0;
        for(int i = 1 ; i < rows ; i++)
        {
            dist[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        for(int k = 0 ; k < rows - 1 ; k++)
        {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0 ; j < rows ; j++)
                {
                    if(i != j && dist[i] != Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                    {
                        if(dist[j] > dist[i] + times[i][j])
                        {
                            dist[j] = dist[i] + times[i][j];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < rows ; j++)
            {
                if(i != j && dist[j] > dist[i] + times[i][j])
                    return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The excessive formatting makes it look like you wrote the entire post in crayon. Please use markup sparingly and for its intended purpose.

Comment: The Stackoverflow problem happened because the number of nested recursive calls is large (A calls B calls C ....), it will eat up all the memory, thus creating the error. One way to test is you need to create a large test case and set your stack memory to an appropriate size (which resembles the real environment). One way fix this problem is to change from recursive to iterative approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Floyd–Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) to check whether graph contains negative cycles, but you should not only check, but remove them(!). With reduced graph you don't have cycles in your path and maximum possible path contains of 5 bunnies + entrance + exit, so total 7 elements without any stack overflow.

In case there are negative cycles on vertices you should check them first and return all bunnies if they exist. If negative cycle on a vertex exists it means that you have unlimited time resources, so you can collect every bunny without worrying about time.

There are following steps to execute:

1. Reduce graph removing negative cycles.
2. Check for negative cycles on vertices.
3. Generate all possible paths (for max 5 bunnies brute-force is acceptable).
4. Select best path in correct order.